# Error when click on EditView in custom dialog box in the hands of place of EditView in layout

Tags: android, textview, dialog

When you click EditView (textStandardSMS) custom dialog box with EditView appears where you can enter text. But when I click on EditView in the dialogue, the keyboard is showing and then starts some error. 
Everything is fine when I pulled  "textStandardSMS" to the "main" layout window.

Here layout that causes the errors:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/startLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/tlo_m"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/startLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageONOFF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/power_1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="fHelp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_info_details" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="fHistory"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_send" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="fTempleteSMS"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_compose" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/startLayout3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/startLayout4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbStandardSMS"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bucik_cb_1"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bEditStandardSMS"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="fGetTemplateStandard"
            android:src="@drawable/add_template" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textStandardSMS"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ramka5"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="fEditStandardSMS"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/startLayout5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/startLayout6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cBOutSMS"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bucik_cb_1"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bEditOut"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="fGetTemplateOut"
            android:src="@drawable/add_template" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextOut"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ramka5"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="fEditOutSMS"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/startLayout7"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:text="@string/MessagesList"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="fAddProfil"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_add" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="true" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the one that no causes the errors:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/startLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/tlo_m"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/startLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageONOFF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/power_1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="fHelp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_info_details" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="fHistory"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_send" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="fTempleteSMS"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_compose" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/startLayout3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/startLayout4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbStandardSMS"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bucik_cb_1"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bEditStandardSMS"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="fGetTemplateStandard"
            android:src="@drawable/add_template" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textStandardSMS"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ramka5"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="fEditStandardSMS"
    android:text="@string/empty"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/startLayout5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/startLayout6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cBOutSMS"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bucik_cb_1"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bEditOut"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="fGetTemplateOut"
            android:src="@drawable/add_template" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextOut"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ramka5"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="fEditOutSMS"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/startLayout7"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:text="@string/MessagesList"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="fAddProfil"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_add" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="true" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Could anyone tell me, why this is happening?